# Build fail with HelloWorld project and no idea what to do

Tags: cordova, gradle, build

I tried to build this simple project using Windows 10.

I'm using Gradle 7.0.2.

Not sure what to do.

This is the error I received:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
File C:\Users\pc 2019\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Users\pc 2019\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 29 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
 platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
 To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components     using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see     http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: C:\Users\pc 2019\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```